# I get 4 when I use scanf_s but 1 when I use fgets()?

Tags: c++, scanf, fgets, cpu-word

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char s[200];
    int count = 0, i;

    printf("enter the string\n");
    //scanf_s("%[^\n]s", s, sizeof(s));
    fgets(s, sizeof*(s), stdin);
    for (i = 0;s[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ')
        count++;
    }
    printf("number of words in given string are: %d\n", count + 1);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Why does one function have `sizeof(s)` and the other `sizeof*(s)`?

Comment: that's a typo! sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fgets(s, sizeof*(s), stdin);`  -- is wrong. it should be `sizeof(s)`

The *(s) is character (first element of array), while s is array. Because single character is of size 1, you got 1.

Comment: i get the correct output after i changed sizeof*(s) to sizeof(s). Thanks

Comment: Well... now you know that the sizeof-operator eschewes parentheses when applied to an expression. (And one should avoid applying it to a type anyway.)